# Is there a command using svn to to show the revisions in the last 24 hours?

Tags: perl, svn

I am currently using svn to track changes in text files in a few directories. I am using the below code (portion of the whole program) to extract the current revision number and display it in a perl/cgi script using xml. My goal would be to display a different color number for the svn revisions that have been changed in the last 24 hours (or day). I thought there was a way to do it with the svn --recursive function. I know how to look at specific dates, but this is constantly being updated.

```
my $SVNInfoXML=`svn --recursive --xml info data/text/`;
my $SVNInfo=XMLin($SVNInfoXML);
my %FileInfo=();my $SVNLatestRev=0;
for my $entry (@{$SVNInfo->{entry}}) {
    $FileInfo{File::Basename::basename($entry->{path},'.diff')}=$entry;
    $SVNLatestRev=($entry->{revision}>$SVNLatestRev)?$entry->{revision}:$SVNLatestRev;}
```

Later down in the program I print a table in HTML displaying the the most recent svn revision number; however, I need to see not only the number, but also if it was revised in the last day.

Comment: Maybe Revision dates can help you: see "Revision dates" paragraph  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html . svn log -r {...}:{...} URL

Comment: I looked at that, but as I mentioned, the dates are not consistent, I care about the last day only. Unless there is a way to do something like `svn log -r {sysdate-1} {sysdate}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Perl script. Right?

Why not let Perl figure out what 24 hours earlier time wise is, and then use `Time::Piece` to parse the Subversion dates?

In fact, why are you using `svn info` and not simply `svn log --xml`. That will give you the history of all the changes, and you merely have to look at each date and see if it matches your older date.

To get the time from 24 hours before, you can use this:

```
use Time::Piece
use Time::Seconds    #Constants that come in handy

my $current_time = localtime;
my $yesterday_time = $current_time - ONE_DAY;
```

Now, `$yesterday_time` is 24 hours before.

If you use `XML::Simple`, you can get the format of the `svn log --xml $file` output into a handy structure. Here's a simple test program I wrote:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use XML::Simple qw(xml_in xml_out);
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $file_name = "?Some Name?";

my $now = localtime;
my $yesterday_time = $now - ONE_DAY;

open (my $xml_file, "-|", qq(svn log --xml "$file_name"));

my $xml = xml_in($xml_file);

# XML is a reference to a hash with a single key 'logentry'
# This points to a reference to an array and each entry is
# a reference to a hash that contains the four pieces to the
# log entry.

my $entries_ref = $xml->{logentry};

foreach my $entry (@{$entries_ref}) {

    # Each entry is a reference to a hash

    my $revision = $entry->{revision};
    my $author = $entry->{author};
    my $date = $entry->{date};
    my $message = $entry->{msg};

    # For giggles, we print out the four items.
    # In truth, there could be more than four items
    # in the hash if there was also a revprop too.

    say "$revision: $author: $date: $message";

    # The date is in 100,000 of a second. We need to get
    # rid of everything on the other side of the seconds
    # decimal before we manipulate it.

    $date =~ s/\.\d+Z$//;   # Get rid of 10,000 of seconds

    # Now, we can convert the "svn log" date to a Time::Piece
    my $rev_date = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");

    # Compare the rev date to the $yesterday_time date
    if ($rev_date < $yesterday_time) {
        say "Revision $revision is older than one day"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jonny That was actually a rhetorical question. You mentioned this was a Perl script in your question. Did the information I give you help? Can you use Perl instead of Subversion to determine whether or not a change is over 24 hours old?

Comment: I have been looking at it for a while, trying to determine if I could work it in. In the long run, I am seeking to color code HTML based on subversion. I want to be implementing logic to check if the subversion date had been modified in the last day, and then adjust the HTML color based on that fact. Also I was using info because log was not giving necessarily giving me all the information i needed

Comment: @Jonny Then go ahead and use `svn info --recursive`. The logic is the same: Use `Time::Piece` & `Time::Seconds` to determine _yesterday_. Then go through and parse your XML. When you get a date in the XML, use `Time::Piece->strpfmt` to convert the date into a Time::Piece object. Then, you can compare it to your calculated _yesterday_ date.

I didn't do the HTML display, but there's no reason why this can't be a CGI script. In the `if ( $rev_date < $yesterday_time )` statement, use a different color in the `<font>` element, or use the CSS class for earlier dates vs. later dates.